# Returning most common paths in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a very simple structure:

```
U1-:VISITS->P1-:VISITS->P2-:VISITS->P3-VISITS->P4...
```

Each VISITS relationship has a rating on a scale 1 to 10. I am interested in relationships that start with U1-:VISITS->P1-:VISITS->P2 where 1st rating is <2 and 2nd rating is greater than 5. Each page node has page link as a property. After that, I am interested in the next 2 pages the user visits. This should return a list of paths. I am interested in the most frequent paths the user takes and ordering them number of times they appear. My query doesn't return the correct count of paths. What did I do wrong?

```
MATCH p=(a)-[r:VISITS]-(b)-[t:VISITS]-(c)-[q*1..2]-(page:Page) WHERE r.rating<2 AND t.rating>5 RETURN EXTRACT (n IN nodes(p)|n.page_id) ,count(p) ORDER BY count(p) DESC;
```

For example:

```
U1->P1->P2
U2->P1->P2
U3->P3->P4
```

should have

```
P1,P2  2
P3,P4  1
```

as the final result.

EDIT: This is my solution that returns the correct result for the above problem (u->p1->p2):

```
MATCH p=(a)-[r:VISITS]-(b:Page)-[t:VISITS]-(page:Page) WHERE r.rating<2 AND t.rating>5 WITH EXTRACT (n IN nodes(p)|n.page_id) AS my_pages,t AS rels RETURN DISTINCT(my_pages) AS pages,count(DISTINCT rels) as count;
```

I need to extend it now to include longer paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that I notice (and it make have just been a transcription error, is that there are no directions on the relationships.  Also, you're not using labels, so you could be matching on any sub-section of the path.  This might work better:

```
MATCH p=(a:User)-[r:VISITS]->(b:Page)-[t:VISITS]->(c:Page)-[q*1..2]->(page:Page)
  WHERE r.rating<2 AND t.rating>5
  RETURN EXTRACT (n IN nodes(p)|n.page_id) ,count(p)
  ORDER BY count(p) DESC;
```

If you don't have labels, you could maybe also add `WHERE NOT(()-[:VISITS]->(a))`

Comment: Yes, for some reason I didn't use directions and that was one of the reasons I didn't get the correct result. I probably didn't explain correctly in the original post, but I am looking to count the number of identical paths, not to count the number of nodes in the path.

Comment: Hrmm, interesting.  Maybe `RETURN count(DISTINCT p)`?

Comment: I clarified the original question. I am not looking to count the number of nodes, I am trying to return the count of distinct paths. RETURN count(DISTINCT p) would return 5, while I am looking for 3. The reason it is returning 5 is that it is counting U1->P1 and then U1->P1->P2, while it should be counting only U1->P1->P2

Comment: Ah, maybe your relationship match should be `(c:Page)-[q*2]->(page:Page)` then