# neo4j slow in returning paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a very simple structure:

```
U1-:VISITS->P1-:VISITS->P2-:VISITS->P3-VISITS->P4...
```

Each VISITS relationship has a rating on a scale 1 to 10. I am interested in relationships that start with U1-:VISITS->P1-:VISITS->P2 where 1st rating is <2 and 2nd rating is greater than 5. Each page node has page link as a property. After that, I am interested in the next 2 pages the user visits. This should return a list of paths. I am interested in the most frequent paths the user takes and ordering them number of times they appear.

For example:

```
U1->P1->P2
U2->P1->P2
U3->P3->P4
```

should have

```
P1,P2  2
P3,P4  1
```

My solution

```
MATCH p=(a)-[r:VISITS]->(b:Page)-[t:VISITS]->(page:Page) WHERE r.rating<2 AND t.rating>5 
WITH EXTRACT (n IN nodes(p)|n.page_id) AS my_pages,t AS rels RETURN DISTINCT(my_pages) 
AS pages,count(DISTINCT rels) as count;
```

This is very slow (on 1 million nodes it takes 360733 ms (I have allocated more than enough memory). If I add another hop

```
p=(a)-[r:VISITS]->(b:Page)-[t:VISITS]->(page:Page)-[s:VISITS]->(page:Page)
```

where s.rating>5, the query never finishes (or it takes too long to finish). Is there any way to make the query faster? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of a question asked a few days ago?

Comment: I recognize the first listed path in the question, which isn't even entirely directed or syntactically valid.

Comment: Yup, mostly a copy (but slightly different) than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450470/returning-most-common-paths-in-neo4j

Comment: What indexes do you have in place? What are your node cache settings?  How much memory does your JVM use?  What have you read and done from this link:   http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-performance.html

Comment: Hi! this is not a duplicate. Why isn't the path syntactically valid? I allocated 8G for JVM and 10-20GB for relationships, node storage etc in groovy settings.

Comment: This bit:  `P1-:VISITS->P2` in your first line of code isn't really "cypherese".  You can't refer to relationship types outside of [brackets] like that, and in other cases (`P3-VISITS->P4`) you don't even indicate that visits is a relationship type.

Comment: This was an example. Each VISITS relationship has a timestamp and rating attached to it as properties.

Comment: So... `a` is a user? Do you have a label for them to differentiate those nodes from the `Page` nodes? I would start with that. You probably have many more `Page` nodes than `User` nodes. Does the `User` visit subsequent `Pages` (i.e. after the first) or do the `Pages` visit `Pages`?

Comment: User can visit one or more pages. Yes, I have a label User. I changed the code so that I first do (a)-[r:VISITS]->(b:Page), carry out b in the second query, but it's still really slow. I downsized to 10K nodes and it's still taking over 1min

Comment: I think what @DaveBennet is suggesting is that you include the `User` label in your query. That is, `(a:User)` instead of `(a)`. This might speed up you query, since it will (greatly?) reduce the number of nodes that are matched against `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @cybersam and @DaveBenett suggested you should assign a label to your users. Additionally it might make sense to help Cypher with early termination of branches by introducing `WITH` statements:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[r:VISITS]->(b:Page)
WHERE r.rating < 2
WITH u, b
MATCH (b)-[t:VISITS]->(page:Page)
WHERE t.rating > 5
RETURN ....
```